# Packages, Modules, and classes within those

Tags: python, module, package

What is the "correct" way to import/use classmethods when my class is part of a module?

I created a Python utility for my co-workers, basically using my Java knowledge, Stack Overflow and Google. It works fine, but an experienced Python person reviewed everything and suggested to improve the pythonicity of the code.

Initially, I just used `sys.path.append()` to add sub-directories that would contain many `.py` files (basically one class within each `.py`).

Now I am trying to get the thing working with packages and modules:

1. I added (empty) `__init__.py` files in my root directory, and all sub-directories;
2. I turned all my classes into "modules", by adding `__name__ = "whatever-filename"` at line 1.

And, well, imports work. In my main script, I can do

```
from classes import MyHelper
```

(where `classes` refers to a sub-directory, and `MyHelper` to a module within). But:

```
MyHelper.some_class_method()
```

gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xyz", line 12, in <module>
MyHelper.some_class_method()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'some_class_method'
```

But I didn't change `MyHelper` - it still has all the `@classmethod`s that I could use before introducing packages/modules.

Edit: MyHelper looks like this:

```
__name__ = "MyHelper"
...
class MyHelper(object):
    """This class..."""
...
```

Comment: Can you add the file where MyHelper is defined?

Comment: "I turned all my classes into "modules", by adding __name__ = "whatever-filename" at line 1." : How is this supposed to "turn your classes into "module"" ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Well, I am told: a .py file that starts with `__name__ = ...` is basically a module. So before the change, it is a python file containing a class; and afterwards it is a module; containing a class?!

Comment: @Jägermeister who told you that? Per [the actual docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html): *"Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, I guess then I misinterpreted the online documentation. Thank you folks for clarifying!

Comment: @Jägermeister: this might help (the whole chapter): https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyHelper` refers to a module name when imported, not the class name which is the same. You can try the following import instead to import a class from a module in a child directory.

```
from classes.MyHelper import MyHelper
MyHelper.calling_my_class_method_here()
```

Comment: OK; I see. That code looks ugly; but it works. Are there ways to "beautify" it; for example to avoid "MyHelper" to show up "twice"?

Comment: @Jägermeister: yes, 1. just avoid the java-ish "one class per file" and 2. don't use classes when a plain function is enough. A typical Python module will contain a set of related functions and classes. Also avoid CamelCase for modules names, they should be all_lower.

Comment: I'd keep the classes in the same file, could you please mark as answer?

Comment: @Jägermeister you can put `from MyHelper import MyHelper` in the `__init__.py` for `classes`, then `from classes import MyHelper` accesses the class rather than the module.

Answer (score -1):

> from X import Y

is really importing a class or function Y from the module X into the current module's namespace, and you can use Y directly.

Alternatively, if you just imported the module X, eg

> import X

then you would call the function (or class) Y as X.Y. So in your case, try just

> import MyHelper
>
> MyHelper.some_class_method()

Comment: So basically, you are suggesting the OP should use the very exact code that raised an AttributeError and led him to post here ?